# Move a page to another place in a djvu file

Tags: djvu

I was wondering how to move a page to another place in a djvu file?

For example, I wish page 7 can be moved to be between page 10 and 11, where all the page numbers are specified relative to the original djvu file. In other words, page 8~10, 7 in the original djvu file becomes page 7~9, 10 in the new djvu file.

I have heard of djvused, but am not sure if it can be of help.

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 - simple

Download the English version of [DJVU TOY](http://www.comicer.com/stronghorse/software/exe/DjVuToy_eng.zip).  This allows you to split and merge documents as you see fit. It is very straight forward. Here are the [man pages](http://www.comicer.com/stronghorse/software/html/DjVuToy.htm).  You will need Google translate to translate the pages into English.  I use Chrome so it was not a problem.

Simply split your entire document.  Change the page ordering/numbering in the folder and then merge.

Solution 2 - more difficult, djvuextract is poorly documented.

You can use [DJVUEXTRACT](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/djvuextract.html) to extract pages from a DJVU file and [DJVUMAKE](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/djvumake.html) to reassemble the file.

All are part of the [DJVULibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) project. It is a pretty cool library and will do most things you need.  It runs on Ubuntu too of course.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure about the manpages for the two commands. Suppose the djvu file's name is myfile.djvu, how shall I generate another new file new.djvu, with page 8~10, 7 in the original djvu file being page 7~9, 10 in the new djvu file?

Comment: @Tim Did you get sorted? If not, I will look at this tomorrow. Could you explain what you need, I am still a little confused...

Comment: Thanks! My intention was to move page 7 to page 10. I still don't quite understand how that can be achieved by DJVUEXTRACT and DJVUMAKE?

Comment: So, page 10 becomes page 7, and page 10 becomes page 11, i that correct?  So the order in the new file is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, [*7 removed], 8, 9, [*7 inserted], 10, 11, 12 ...

Comment: Almost, page 7 in the old file becomes page 10 in the new file, i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, [*7 removed], 8, 9, 10, [*7 inserted], 11, 12 ...

Comment: Cool. Will add answer later.

Comment: @Tim Check out the new answer. Works great.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be nice under Windows. I tried it with Wine under Ubuntu, and it works although it also increases the size of the files more than 10 times during splitting and merging.

Answer (score 0):

```
djvused myfile.djvu -e "select 7; save-page p07.djvu"
djvm -i myfile.djvu p07.djvu 11
djvm -d myfile.djvu 7
```

Here the approach is to extract page 7, insert its copy at the desired location and then delete the original one.